# program crashes when Orientation change from portrait to landscape

Tags: android, gridview, indexoutofboundsexception, android-orientation

I have a strange behavior in my app. I am using one gridview and a imageadapter class. Now if I change my phone orientation from portrait to landscape it crashes. But if I change from landscape from portrait it works perfectly fine. I have two separate layouts for portrait and landscape stored in res/layout and res/layout-land

This is my activity class

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedBundle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.rashi_grid);
    RashiImageAdapter adapter = new RashiImageAdapter(RashiFragmentActivity.this);
    int count = adapter.getCount();
    System.out.println("Total Count From RashiFragmentactivity:-"+count);

    StaggeredGridView gridView = (StaggeredGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(StaggeredGridView parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent product = new Intent(RashiFragmentActivity.this,productActivity.class);
            product.putExtra("productname", position);
            startActivity(product);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

This is my imageadapter class

```
 private Context mycontext;
 private LayoutInflater mInflater;

 public Integer ImageId[]={
    R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d,
    R.drawable.e,R.drawable.f
};

public String productName[]={
        "a","b","c",
        "d","e","f"
};

public String productprice[]={
    "2450"  ,"3990", "2490","2490","5100","1350"
};

public RashiImageAdapter(Context context)
{
    mycontext = context;
     mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ImageId.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder vh;

    if (v == null)
    {
    vh = new ViewHolder();
    v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid,parent,false);
    vh.productname = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.productname);
    vh.productprice = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
    vh.productpricedetails = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.product_pricedetails);
    vh.imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

    v.setTag(vh); 
    }
    else 
    { 
    vh = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();  
    }       

    vh.productpricedetails.setText(productprice[position]);
    vh.productname.setText(productName[position]);
    vh.imageView.setImageResource(ImageId[position]);
    vh.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    return v;
}
```

This is my gridview xml file for portrait

```
      <com.origamilabs.library.views.StaggeredGridView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:staggered="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
   staggered:numColumns="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    staggered:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
   android:layout_marginRight="0.5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
     android:layout_gravity="top"
     android:stretchMode="columnWidth"         
     />
```

and for landscape

```
       <com.origamilabs.library.views.StaggeredGridView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:staggered="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
   staggered:numColumns="2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    staggered:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
   android:layout_marginRight="0.5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
     android:layout_gravity="top"
     android:stretchMode="columnWidth"         
     />
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Logcat Error

```
          12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
        12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):     at com.origamilabs.library.views.StaggeredGridView.populate(StaggeredGridView.java:966)
          12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):   at com.origamilabs.library.views.StaggeredGridView.onLayout(StaggeredGridView.java:920)
       12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
       12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
     12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
     12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
    12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
    12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
  12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
  12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
   12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
   12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
   12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
 12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1997)
   12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1818)
  12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
  12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4526)
  12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
 12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
 12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
 12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
  12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
 12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
 12-02 11:37:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(7880):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

One more thing is..If I change the column size 2 to 1 in layout-land/grid.xml file then the error is not coming. It's working fine. Why is ithis strange behavior? How can I accomplish my code to change portrait to landscape and the layout should be change according to that like what is happening in landscape to portrait. If landscape to portrait working fine then why it's not working portrait to landscape?

Comment: Where is your logcat error ?

Comment: Post your logcat error.

Comment: Have you bind your `GridView` again on orientation change from portrait to landscape ?

Comment: I have updated my logcat error...

Comment: @GrIsHu I am not oveririding orientationchange method.I am having no problem in activity recreation.I want that system automatically takes the layout on orientation change.But its not working on potrait to landscape

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.This is a bug of the StaggeredGridView Library.

I am posting the solution if anyone faces the same problem.

You need to change StaggeredGridView.java class the below codes

```
        final int top = getPaddingTop();
    for(int i = 0; i<colCount; i++){
        final int offset =  top + ((mRestoreOffsets != null)? Math.min(mRestoreOffsets[i], 0) : 0);
        mItemTops[i] = (offset == 0) ? mItemTops[i] : offset;
        mItemBottoms[i] = (offset == 0) ? mItemBottoms[i] : offset;
```

to this code

```
              final int top = getPaddingTop();
    for(int i = 0; i<colCount; i++){
    // final int offset =  top + ((mRestoreOffsets != null)? Math.min(mRestoreOffsets[i], 0) : 0);
        int offset = top;
        if((mRestoreOffsets != null) && mRestoreOffsets.length == colCount)
          offset +=  Math.min(mRestoreOffsets[i], 0);
       mItemTops[i] = (offset == 0) ? mItemTops[i] : offset;
       mItemBottoms[i] = (offset == 0) ? mItemBottoms[i] : offset;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change orientation the override method is called :

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

when you change the orientation the view is reload again then you have to hold your values in `onSaveInstanceState` method and restore or apply values to view in `onRestoreInstanceState`...